# Using right image for creating hope for the user to take action

Tags: interface-design, mobile, android

I am developing educations app where i need to use an image for the first time users which create hope that they will catch up withe their alumni friends. So for this i am using this image.[image]

with some text but it looks odd on screen(real device)[image]

Can i make this kind of image which create nostalgia/hope for user to take action or it would be better to use some clip art of educations institutes ?

Comment: Seems more like a Graphic Design Stack Exchange question

Comment: @LukeSawczak may be you are right.